# Slice a message from python string

Tags: python, substring

I am retrieving an error message in String format. Out of which I have to slice out the message. I have tried converting it into a list but that is making the whole message in to separate list. Tried python substring/slicing but not able to retrieve the message.

The error message looks like this

```
    (vmodl.fault.InvalidArgument) {
   dynamicType = <unset>,
   dynamicProperty = (vmodl.DynamicProperty) [],
   msg = 'A specified parameter was not correct. \nspec.name',
   faultCause = <unset>,
   faultMessage = (vmodl.LocalizableMessage) [
      (vmodl.LocalizableMessage) {
         dynamicType = <unset>,
         dynamicProperty = (vmodl.DynamicProperty) [],
         key = 'com.vmware.vim.vpxd.dvs.uniqueField1.label',
         arg = (vmodl.KeyAnyValue) [
            (vmodl.KeyAnyValue) {
               dynamicType = <unset>,
               dynamicProperty = (vmodl.DynamicProperty) [],
               key = 'dvs1',
               value = 'ExampleDVS1'
            },
            (vmodl.KeyAnyValue) {
               dynamicType = <unset>,
               dynamicProperty = (vmodl.DynamicProperty) [],
               key = 'prop',
               value = 'spec.name'
            },
            (vmodl.KeyAnyValue) {
               dynamicType = <unset>,
               dynamicProperty = (vmodl.DynamicProperty) [],
               key = 'value',
               value = 'ExampleDVS1'
            },
            (vmodl.KeyAnyValue) {
               dynamicType = <unset>,
               dynamicProperty = (vmodl.DynamicProperty) [],
               key = 'op',
               value = 'create'
            },
            (vmodl.KeyAnyValue) {
               dynamicType = <unset>,
               dynamicProperty = (vmodl.DynamicProperty) [],
               key = 'dvs2',
               value = 'ExampleDVS1'
            }
         ],
         message = 'A VDS ExampleDVS1 with spec.name as ExampleDVS1 already exists, cannot create VDS ExampleDVS1'
      }
   ],
   invalidProperty = u'spec.name'
}
```

As you can see there is a message field which I want to retrieve as `'A VDS ExampleDVS1 with spec.name as ExampleDVS1 already exists, cannot create VDS ExampleDVS1'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
re.search(r"message\s+=\s+'([^']*)'",text_string,re.M).group(1)
```

Comment: ;) @sundarnatarajСундар